# Vue.js error when I'm trying to import library

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, mobile, bluetooth

I'm embarrassed because I don't know why my library don't work.

Notice : I'm a beginner with Vue.js

I have install a library call "Bluetooth Serial", and I want to use it in a component, but after a lot of try it still doesn’t work

I In my entry point main.js

```
import BluetoothSerial from "@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial/ngx";
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$bluetoothSerial', { value: BluetoothSerial });
```

In my component :

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "WattComponent",
  props: {},
  methods: {
    scan: function() {
      this.checkBluetoothEnabled();
    },

    checkBluetoothEnabled: function() {
      this.$bluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then(
        success => {
          console.log("enabled");
        },
        error => {
          console.log("erro");
        }
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And it's retuning :

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEnabled' of undefined"

found in

---> <WattComponent> at src/components/WattComponent.vue
       <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

In your main.js (where Vue instance is created at):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import BluetoothSerial from "@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial/ngx";

Vue.prototype.$bluetoothserial = BluetoothSerial;
```

And in your .vue files:

```
methods: {
   foo(){
       this.$bluetoothserial.isEnabled().then(() => {
          //some code here
       });
   }
}
```